Are there still banks of issue in the eurozone that allow citizens to open accounts directly at the central bank?
In France, any citizen or business could open an account and borrow directly at the banque de France, the French central bank in addition to la banque postale from Napoleon to 1992 when the possibility was restricted to peoples working at the central bank and accounts opened before in order to join the eurozone.
In 1939, 39% of businesses had their accounts directly at Banque de France. Following the 2008 crisis, a few very large French companies started their own bank with the sole purpose of being allowed to host their funds directly at the central bank.
In communist countries like east Germany, central banks tended to be the only allowed banks of their respesctive communist regimes but I’m not aware of one of them not being closed after 1989.
Today various central bank scheme still exists in the Eurozone, like the central bank of Greece being still traded on the stock exchange where any people of the world can buy its shares.
But in light of cbdc, are there still central banks in the eurozone that allow individuals opening checking accounts directly ? Or the negative interest rate period closed that era everywhere ?
As an additional question, I noticed François Hollande took a decree in 2015 to allow money transmistting businesses (essentially banks that can’t lend money) to open accounts directly at the Banque de France. So are there such N26 like services having the money of their clients hosted directly at a bank of issue instead of a commercial lending bank ?
Update :
I’m not asking for recommendations but I’m just curious.

What does negative interest have to do with your question? What is cbdc? How's publicly traded relevant to the type of services or authority? Your question is even less clear after your edits.

@littleadv negative interest rate affact all checking accounts. So individuals would have to pay the issuing bank interest in addition of account fees. Commercial banks in the eurozone almost all shielded their customers from the interest rates they were paying to issuing banks or the ecb. Tradeable issuing bank highlight how systems in europe are different and thus it’s not because banque de France has to stop retail banking that all other similar eurozone bank did the same.

I think you're confused. Negative interest rates refer to ecb's interbank lending, not retail. You seem to be confusing a lot of unrelated things here.

@littleadv it affected both interbank lending and interest on deposits on account of bank of issue/central bank. https://www.bde.es/wbe/en/areas-actuacion/politica-monetaria/politica-monetaria-area-euro/nuevos-instrumentos-politica-monetaria/que-significa-que-los-tipos-de-interes-sean-negativos-.html This negative values of interest rates meant that banks had to pay to deposit funds in their accounts at the ECBAny indivual having an account directly at the ecb or an issuing bank would had to pay such negative interest rate.This made commercial bank with no such interest rate more competitive

What do you mean with "it made commercial banks more competitive"? Negative interest rates were a huge burden for commercial banks. Just look at the net interest income of banks over time

@AKdemy it was a huge burden for commercial banks simply because almost none of them passed such negative interest on the deposit of their customers. Any individual having an account at bank of issue had to pay a 0.5%apy on their deposit during years compared to typically 0% in a commercial bank.

@user2284570 you still can't explain what any of that negative interest nonsense has to do with anything. Central banks are not in it to make money.

@littleadv Interest rate policy from the ecb is for all accounts at the central bank. If a bank charge you interests rate on the deposits of your checking account and most bank does not, you close your account at your current bank (bank of issue in the eurozone) and move to a commercial bank that doesn’t charge interests.

Central banks generally are not intended to provide retail services. The French central bank (Banc de France) is somewhat unique. There's also a bit of confusion between the concepts of "bank of issue" and "central bank". The former refers to an authority to print money, the latter refers to the authority to oversee banking systems and determine monetary policy. In the UK, for example, issuing authority is within several banks (England and Wales are served by Bank of England, Scotland and Northern Ireland have their own issuers), while the monetary policy is the responsibility of the Bank of England.
In the Soviet bloc, it is not true that the central bank provided retail services either. In the USSR, for example, the central bank was "GosBank" (literally - State Bank), but the retail services were provided by the "SberBank" (literally - savings bank). The SberBank actually predates the USSR, and survived it, still existing.
The reason the French Bank allowed retail services was to make them accessible to those who otherwise don't have access (the unbanked people). From the bank itself, the relevant part of the mission statement:

Helping the general public with formalities and supporting business professionals
Our branches are open to any person – both private individuals and professionals – encountering financial difficulties (overindebtedness) or struggling to access basic financial services (opening an account, microloans, etc.). We help business leaders with their management and banking relations.

In many countries (including France) these services are now provided by postal banks. In some countries this system still exists, including in the EU.

In the comments, the OP seems to obsess about the ECB negative interest issue. It is not relevant to anything, obviously, since it refers to the inter-bank lending rates and not retail rates (although retail rates are affected by it). The central banks are not in the business of making money, which is why most (if not all) of them have been nationalized. Those who do provide retail services - do not do it for profit, as exemplified with the French bank mission statement. Comparing central banks with commercial retail banks makes little sense - they exist for completely different reasons and purposes.

With many French peoples complaining at the idea of cbdc and thus forgetting a 180 years history, I’m thinking there are still central banks in the eurozone offering accounts to arbitrary individuals (and thus each central banks of the eurozone should be checked first before saying this is no longer possible). Also banque de France is still central bank managed by the ecb. When the ecb want to buy French bonds, it’s banque de France who create the money and the debt is paid to banque de France.

Also wrong. Banque de France offering retail service is not linked to bank the unbanked as la banque postale exists for more than 150 years. I wasn’t talking about ussr but other eastern europpean communist countries. Check east Germany for example.

Please don't try to mutilate my answer. What is the point of your question and aggressive comments? No one is going to check each and every country for you here.

A part of your answer was simply wrong. There were many post offfices but banque de France has only 1 branch per city. Post offices of Banque de Frances were 2 different banks were each of them offering retail banking services (with la banque postale having an account at banque de France like any commercial bank with the difference to be owned by the state).

One doesn't have to contradict the other, postal bank was established way later than banc de France.

Yep but at a time banque de France had the monopoly of money only on Paris. Definitely unrelated to making money accessible. In fact, with the fear of statewide monopoly by Napoleon 3, they were huge pushback against the banque of France opening additional branches. Banque de France allowed retail banking simply by being a privately owned commercial bank and behaving like any commercial bank. Ptt on the hand was always state owned. banque de France providing retail banking for accessibility is simply completely untrue

I lost you completely. I don't know what you're asking or arguing against. You're rambling.

I’m just telling you a part of your answer is wrong. Banque de France offering retail service had no link with making banking accessible.

@user2284570 again, you say that - but you have no reference for that. You just think that I'm wrong, but you don't bother checking. You made up your mind, and the reality and facts won't change your opinion. I'll give you a couple of more days to look it up yourself and then will put the link to my reference.

I’m French in terms of experience with relative. Yourself have no reference for telling it was to make banking accessible. Banque postale and before ptt was for the unbanked and still is today. Banque de France branches are only in downtown of large cities (the worst accessibility compared to any other bank). A reason for nationalization was banque de France largely operated like any commercial bank and owners set interest rates as they pleased until 1936.

@user2284570 you misunderstand the term "accessibility" in this context. In any case, the question was closed, rightly so, but feel free to ask about any of the terms that you've used in this discussion. Didn't mean to offend you, but you clearly lack some understanding of the terms you're using.

You confuse things : banque de France mission statement is from it’s order by law to give access to a bank account : you request to banque de France to compel a commercial bank at random to open an account. This is 1 of it’s missions among many. This has no link with 1803 Napoleon Bonaparte caring about peoples not getting bank account or the poor in general.
